# How to split numbers into individual

Tags: javascript

I have this whole number **75892**. i want to split it in individual and then add below is my code. it works fine but **is there any other solution to minimize my code?** thanks

```
var x=75892;
var d,ans=0;
while(x!=0){
    d=x%10;
    ans=ans+d;
    x=parseInt(x/10);
}
document.write("SUM:"+ans);
```

Comment: *"i want to split it in individua"* What does that mean? It's important when asking questions like this to be clear about what you're trying to do. A minimum here, for instance, would be to tell us what sum you expect.

Comment: Why do you want to minimize it for? It doesn't appear in the tittle if its the main subject of your post...

Comment: @Pal3Kuno May I know minimize code means execution time or less code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanted shorter - here's a one-line ES6 version:

```
var ans = [...(String(x))].map(Number).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
```

Use [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) on a stringified version of `x`, convert them to numbers, then use `reduce` to sum the numbers.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b23ryewu/3/)

Comment: what is the " . . . "?

Comment: That's the [spread operator](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html). Basically, it breaks down an iterable object (in this case the string) into its iterable parts (characters).

Comment: `Array.from(String(x))...` works too and is a bit more legible :)

Answer (score 1):

That approach is fine other than the `parseInt` part. `parseInt` will first convert the number to string, then parse that string. You wanted `Math.floor`:

```
x = Math.floor(x / 10);
```

You can also use `+=` and just generally there are a couple of shortcuts you could take:

```
var x = 75892;
var ans = 0;
while (x != 0) {
    ans += x % 10;
    x = Math.floor(x / 10);
}
document.write("SUM:" + ans);
```

Another approach would be to go through the digits, e.g. a string-based approach instead of a math-based one. But frankly, I don't think it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x="" + 75892;
var sum = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ )
{
 sum += parseInt( x[i] );
}
console.log( "sum: " + sum );
```

Please try this once.

Answer (score 0):

Use, please review [Sum of a string of one-digit numbers in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052254/sum-of-a-string-of-one-digit-numbers-in-javascript)

```
var sum = function(a,b){return a+b}

function stringSum(s) {
    var int = function(x){return parseInt(x,10)}
    return s.split('').map(int).reduce(sum);
}
document.write(stringSum("75892"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is, when i was thought in college days, Now share with you. **Beauty is there is no loop**.

```
var x=75892;
var d,ans = 0;
x = parseInt(x);
if(x < 0){
    x = -1 * x;
}
if(x > 0){
    d = x % 9;
    if(d == 0){
        ans = 9;
    }else{
        ans = d;
    }
}
document.write("SUM:"+ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to split the variable-

```
var x=75892;
var arr = x.split('');
var count=0;
for (var i=arr.length; i--;) {
  count = count+parseInt(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if there's a smarter way, than just peeling off digits at the end, then no - not in the decimal system at least.

Unless you want to reduce to a single digit (eg. 75892 -> 31 -> 4) in which case

```
function(d){
   if(d === 0){
      return 0;
   }
   var m = d%9;
   return m === 0 ? 9 : m;
}
```

will do the trick